# Page not updating when using $set with GoAngular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, goinstant, goangular

I've got a piece of code that looks like this:

```
$scope.renameUser = function(key,name) {
  console.log('renameUser, key: ', key);
  console.log('renameUser, name: ', name);
  var userOne = $scope.users.$key(key);
  userOne.$key('displayName').$set(name);
};
```

It works, but you need to reload the page to see the updated result. I would like it to update instantly.

During debugging I added this part, but I never get it to trigger... Any ideas what is going on?

```
$scope.users.$on('set', opts, function(value) {
   console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Hey Alfred, I'm just working on duplicating the issue now, I'll get back to you in a few!

Comment: Ok I've duplicated, I think I understand the issue, let me see if I can't patch it :)

Comment: I think I've got this patched, version 3.2.2 should be up on the CDN in a few minutes, let me know if you have any other issues :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was introduced in v3.2.0. The `$key` method, whether it's being called on a model returned by a `$goQuery` or `$goKey` should return a 'new' model associated with a 'relative' key.  Instead it was recycling the service associated with the first key used.

This issue has been fixed in v3.2.2, upgrading to this version should resolve your issue.

Thanks for sharing!

Comment: No sweat, if you have any feedback, drop us line :)